# Regex to match other than listed string

Tags: regex

I need to select a value which not listed in following string including all special characters.

List of string and requirement that need to rejected:

- XNIL
- SNIL
- All special characters

My expression is like this `(?!XNIL|SNIL|[\W])\w+`

The problem is, if my text have a word `XNIL` or `SNIL`, it still allow the word `NIL`. But i have listed the word `XNIL` and `SNIL` to be rejected. Any mistake did i made here?

You can check my regex online here -> http://regexr.com/3cdsl

Comment: Given the input in the regxr link, what should match? The questions asks for a value, not mutiple. And given the input, there will be multiple matches no matter what. Perhaps data closer to what you are actually parsing would be better?

Comment: The input text just a dummy data that will used to test the regex expression. In my real case, it will be a single text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work on your test page: `(?!(XNIL|SNIL|\W+))\b\w+`  At least it solves the XNIL/SNIL problem.

The reason why your regex was matching XNIL was it was matching from the `\w+`.  To see why, take your original and change `\w+` to `\w` and notice the difference.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your feedback, you also wish to exclude `_`.

Because `_` is used in programming language symbols, and [arguably] regexes were created, of, by, and for programmers, `_` is considered a "word" char (i.e. it's *in* `\w` and therefore *not* excluded by `\W`).

From the [perl] regex man page:

> \w Match a "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_", plus other connector punctuation chars plus Unicode marks)

Your final regex might need to be: `(?!(XNIL|SNIL|_+|\W+))\b\w+`. (Note: the `_+`)

A cleaner way: `(?!(XNIL|SNIL|[\W_]+))\b\w+` which produces the same results yet is closer in intent to what you wanted.

You *may* have to adjust `\w+` accordingly as well

If you really want to be sure, at the expense of being slightly more verbose, write out the character class as you choose:
`(?!(XNIL|SNIL|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+))\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Comment: thanks. it worked. i noticed special character `_` still allowed. but i can simply put it in the rejected list. so my final regex will be like this `(?!(XNIL|SNIL|_|\W+))\b\w+`

Comment: @ggDeGreat I've posted an update with a slight tweak you may need

Comment: @ggDeGreat You're welcome. Programming is great fun. But, we all get stuck sometimes [usually, it isn't even the "interesting" part of what we're trying to do].  Others on SO like to give "hints" [preserving the "mystique"] because they believe that's a better way to teach. IMO, people learn far more with full explanations/solutions/examples, particularly when, IMO, they've really tried [as you had] and are just "stuck" and the "hints" approach just frustrates the person needing help.  I always try to give the type of answer I would like if I were asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

(?m)^(((?!XNIL|SNIL|[\W]).)*)$

Grouping the character match with the negative lookahead will cause the zero length assertion to continue until finished (in this case at the end of the string due to $)

Comment: not worked. u can try your regex here regexr.com/3cdsl

Comment: sorry, i forgot it needs to be in multiline mode. In regexr remove the `(?m)` and click on the `g` and select multiline

Answer (score 1):

Check this regex

```
[^(XNIL|SNIL|[^\w])]
```

Explanation

1. `[]` having `^` at beginning says the that any thing that is not there in the list given in `[]` should be matched.
2. `(XNIL|SNIL|[^\w+])` matches words `XNIL` or `SNIL` or [^\w] matches anything other than words(i.e. special chars)
3. So the whole regex matches any thing that is not there in `[^(XNIL|SNIL|[^\w])]`

Comment: thanks for your effort, but as u can see, it also reject the text `IL`, `L` and `NI`. it should only reject the whole word `SNIL` and `XNIL`